# Minimum of a maximum function

Tags: functions, optimization

What I'm trying to find is a linear function $y_{fit}$ ($y_{fit}=\beta_1+x\beta_2$) which minimizes the error $S= max(y - y_{fit}) - min(y - y_{fit})$.

In other words, I'm looking for a linear function which if subtracted to the original function $y$ (i.e. $y-y_{fit}$) will give me the minimum $y$ variation.

In simple words I'm trying to "rotate" the original function $y$ in order to obtain the minimum $\Delta y$.

At the moment, I ended up using using the last square method to find this $y_fit$ but the last square method consider the square difference over the full length of vectors $x, y$.

Instead I want to consider only the maximum normal difference!

Hope it's clear... :)

Comment: You need to add more detail. What are the variables you are maximising over, is $y$ a function, etc, etc. Also, if you want to minimise the worst case deviation from $y$, you might consider the $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ norm instead, that is $\max |y-y_\text{fit}|$.

Comment: Thanks copper.hat. The $y$ function is actually a long series of data, so it's not analytically described. So the only variable I'm trying to minimize over are the $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ parameters of the linear function.